# TSQL - Updating column based on bit column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an identity column in my table `[ID]`. I also have a computed column that is based on the identity column like so;

```
create table [dbo].[tblMaster] (
ID bigint identity(1,1),
GlobalFamilyUniqueID int,
DupeIdentifier as cast('EDME' + RIGHT('00000000'+ISNULL(cast([ID] as nvarchar(max)),''),8) as nvarchar(30)),
ControlNumber nvarchar(30),
NuixGuid nvarchar(50),
TopLvlGuid nvarchar(50),
ParentGuid nvarchar(50),
CustodianArtifactID int,
IsGlobalFamilyUnique int,
IsCustodianFamilyUnique int,
IsItemUnique int,
ItemUniqueDupID nvarchar(100),
IsChild int,
GroupIdentifier nvarchar(100),
DatasourceID int,
MD5Hash nvarchar(32),
GlobalFamilyDupID nvarchar(100),
CustodianFamilyDupId nvarchar(100),
ExportSessionID nvarchar(100)
```

)

I want to be update the `ControlNumber` column based on the `IsGlobalFamilyUnique` column. At the minute, `DupeIdentifier` will have a value regardless if `IsGlobalFamilUnique` is `1` or `0`. I need `ControlNumber` to have an incremental value based on the last value in the `ControlNumber` field (I created another column called `GlobalFamilyUnqiueID` as a "counter" column) , but only when `IsGlobalFamilUnique` is `1`.

This is where I am at so far;

```
update x
    set 
    GlobalFamilyUniqueID = [ProposedGlobalFamilyUniqueID],
    ControlNumber = [ProposedControlNumber]
from(
    Select top 10 [id],
        DupeIdentifier,
    --  ControlNumber,
        isglobalfamilyunique,
        --GlobalFamilyUniqueID,
        GlobalFamilyUniqueID,
        Row_Number() Over(Order By [id]) [ProposedGlobalFamilyUniqueID],
        ControlNumber,
        'TEST' + RIGHT('00000000'+ISNULL(cast(Row_Number() Over(Order By [id]) as nvarchar(30)),''),8) [ProposedControlNumber]
    From dbo.tblMaster mstr1
    where IsGlobalFamilyUnique = 1 and ControlNumber is null
)x
```

The problem is that when the code is run again `ProposedGlobalFamilyUniqueID` will start at `1` again. It should start at the last value of `ProposedGlobalFamilyUniqueID` in `dbo.tblMaster`. I assume this is because I am limiting the query to where `ControlNumber is null`, but I don't know how to get around this.

This is an example of the code working successfully the first time its run:
[image]

The end result should be sequential `ControlNumber` values where `IsGlobalFamilyUnique = 1`

**Example Data**

```
 declare @test table (
    ID bigint identity(1,1),
    GlobalFamilyUniqueID int,
    DupeIdentifier as cast('EDME' + RIGHT('00000000'+ISNULL(cast([ID] as nvarchar(max)),''),8) as nvarchar(30)),
    ControlNumber nvarchar(30),
    MD5Hash nvarchar(32),
    IsGlobalFamilyUnique bit
)

insert into @test (MD5Hash, IsGlobalFamilyUnique)values
--1
('ABC', 1),
--2
('DEF', 1),
--3
('GHI', 1),
--4
('JKL', 1),
--5
('ABC', 0),
--6
('XXX', 1)
```

The result should be;
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Just edited to provide sample data!

Answer (score 0):

Keep ControlNumber field as a number, try not to make it varchar because it will be not be able to calculate.

First of all remove all existing control number values before trying script.

Then,try this one:

```
 DECLARE @max as bigint

 SELECT @max = Max(id)

 FROM tblMaster 


  Select [id],
        DupeIdentifier,
    --  ControlNumber,
        isglobalfamilyunique,
        --GlobalFamilyUniqueID,
        GlobalFamilyUniqueID,
        @max + Row_Number() Over(Order By [id]) [ProposedGlobalFamilyUniqueID],
        ControlNumber      
    From dbo.tblMaster mstr1
    where IsGlobalFamilyUnique = 1 and ControlNumber is null


   update x
    set 
    GlobalFamilyUniqueID = [ProposedGlobalFamilyUniqueID],
    ControlNumber =   x.Proposed_Control_Number

from(
    Select [id],
        DupeIdentifier,
    --  ControlNumber,
        isglobalfamilyunique,
        --GlobalFamilyUniqueID,
        GlobalFamilyUniqueID,
        Row_Number() Over(Order By [id]) [ProposedGlobalFamilyUniqueID],
        ControlNumber,
          @max + Row_Number() Over(Order By [id]) as Proposed_Control_Number   
    From dbo.tblMaster mstr1
    Where IsGlobalFamilyUnique = 1 and ControlNumber is null
)x
```